# Finding the General equation of a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ given the middle point between 2 vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

*Determine the equation for the plane consisting of points with the same distance from point $A = (-1,1,2)$ and from point $B = (1,5,-4)$.
The middle point between the distance AB lies on the plane.*

I calculate the middle point:

$$\frac{B-A}{2} = \frac{(1,5,-4)-(-1,1,2)}{2}=\frac{(2, 4,-6)}{2}=(1,2,-3)$$

According to my problem sheet the answer is: $$x+2y-3z=9$$

From where we can clearly see that the normal n of the plane is $n=(1,2,-3)$ which is the middle point we calculated earlier. Here is the plane viewed sideways:

[image: img1]
*Note: the plane in the image is in the form $4x + 8y − 12z = 36$*
     The yellow line is $(1,2,-3)$ our middle point between $\overrightarrow A$ and $\overrightarrow B$ (A is the black line and B is the dotted black line) i.e half of the distance between the arrowheads of A and B plotted from the origin. Which clearly seems to be a plausible normal of the plane.

How do we calculate the equation of the plane

The general equation of the plane has the form $$Ax+By+Cz=d$$
With our normal vector: $$x+2y-3z=d$$
Plugging in the same point $$(1,2,-3)$$ as our $x,y$ and $z$ yields d = 14 which $\neq$ 9 and just seems wrong to use again as a point in our equation.

How do we find d and thereby the general equation of the plane?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the middle point s given by

$$\frac{B\color{red}+A}{2} = \frac{(1,5,-4)+(-1,1,2)}{2}=\frac{(0, 6,-2)}{2}=(0,3,-1)$$

Comment: Why would that be the middle point? If we have 2 points in a plane wouldn't the middle point just be half of the distance between them?

What you wrote is half of the resulting vector from adding A+B and I can't see how that vector can be used for solving the problem

Comment: @Mango164 Think to a simpler problem. What is the middle point between (0,1) ans (0,3)?

Comment: Yes you're right, I was thinking in terms of vectors when they're just points, so (B+A)/2 makes sense.